# Can`t create new files on tftp server

Tags: linux, tftp

I have installed tftpd and xinetd on Ubuntu 13.10 and I have problems with writing to tftp server.
/etc/xinetd.d/tftp file content:

```
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = -c -s /srv/tftp
disable         = no
}
```

File permissions for both /etc/xinetd.d/tftp and /srv/tftp are set on 777.

When I try to put to tftp server or get something from it i get "Transfer timed out." message.

When I change server_args to '-s /srv/tftp' get works fine and put works fine when file which is being put already exists on tftp server.

It is local PC

What should I do to be able to put files, which don't exist on tftp server?

Answer (score 0):

Files do not get created by the `tftp` server, you have to create them (with proper, writable permission bits) before the upload. See `man touch`.

Comment: The "-c" option for (linux) tftpd which the OP  is using enables the creation of files.